# ruby mail gem - set charset in deliver block

Tags: ruby, email, rubygems

I'm using the mail gem to send E-Mail with UTF-8 content using this code

```
Mail.defaults do
    ...
end

Mail.deliver do
    from    "user@example.com"
    to      "otheruser@example.com"
    subject "Mäbülö..."
    body    "Märchenbücher lösen Leseschwächen."
end
```

This works, but gives the warning

```
Non US-ASCII detected and no charset defined.
Defaulting to UTF-8, set your own if this is incorrect.
```

Now after much trying around, consulting mail gem's generated documentation as well as source code, I'm still unable to set the charset. There is a method `charset=` in Message.rb, but when I add a call to charset, like so:

```
Mail.deliver do
    from    "user@example.com"
    to      "otheruser@example.com"
    charset "UTF-8"
    subject "Mäbülö..."
    body    "Märchenbücher lösen Leseschwächen."
end
```

I get this ArgumentError:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/message.rb:1423:in `charset': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

How can I set the charset within the deliver block?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`mail.charset()` returns the current charset, it does not allow to set one and does not take any argument.

To do so you need to use `mail.charset = ...`

It's actually possible inside the block with:

```
Mail.deliver do
  from    "user@example.com"
  to      "otheruser@example.com"
  subject "Mäbülö..."
  body    "Märchenbücher lösen Leseschwächen."
  charset = "UTF-8"
end
```

It's also possible without a block:

```
mail         = Mail.new
mail.charset = 'UTF-8'
mail.content_transfer_encoding = '8bit'

mail.from    = ...
mail.to      = ...
mail.subject = ...

mail.text_part do
  body ...
end

mail.html_part do
  content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
  body ...
end

mail.deliver!
```

Comment: Thank you! Could this be some limitation in the general handling of blocks in ruby, then? Probably an interesting question in itself.

Comment: @gpinkas: I updated my answer as it's actually possible to assign the charset inside the block.

Comment: great, unfortunately I can't +2 you :) thanks for your research!

Comment:  The first example (inside the block) isn't correct. You need to use `self.charset = "UTF-8"` when inside the block. If you say `charset = "UTF-8"`, that's just a local variable assignment and nothing will change.

Answer (score 3):

you need to set the encoding also for the individual parts. Answer by maxdec shows it. Ensure that you do this for the text_part also.

This works for me.

```
mail = Mail.deliver do
  charset='UTF-8'
  content_transfer_encoding="8bit"

  require 'pry';binding.pry
  to      'xxx@xxx.yy'
  from    'yyy@yyy.ss'
  subject "Tet with äöüß"

  text_part do
    content_type "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
    body <<-EOF
       this is a test with äöüß
    EOF
  end
end

mail.deliver!
```

Answer (score 1):

I use mail (2.7.1), neither `charset` nor `content_transfer_encoding` work for me.

```
charset='UTF-8'
content_transfer_encoding="8bit"
```

The following works for me!

```
content_type "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

Comment: Thank you. Using Mail `v2.8.1` I've been trying to find the source of that warning for months but as you point out, setting `content_type xxxx/xxxx; charset=utf-8` worked great for me.